# Mark groups of rows in dataframe based on boolean sequence using pandas approach

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

| point | switch_on |
| --- | --- |
| A | True |
| B | True |
| C | True |
| A | False |
| D | False |
| N | True |
| O | False |
| O | False |
| S | False |

I want to add another column which will determine groups of rows that contain the same boolean before switching. Like this:

| point | switch_on | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | True | 1 |
| B | True | 1 |
| C | True | 1 |
| A | False | 2 |
| D | False | 2 |
| N | True | 3 |
| O | False | 4 |
| O | False | 4 |
| S | False | 4 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify every time there's a change:

- This is when the current value `df.switch_on` doesn't equal the previous value `df.switch_on.shift()`.

Then take the `cumsum`:

- `True` is interpreted as `1`, and `False` as `0`.

```
df['group'] = df.switch_on.ne(df.switch_on.shift()).cumsum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  point  switch_on  group
0     A       True      1
1     B       True      1
2     C       True      1
3     A      False      2
4     D      False      2
5     N       True      3
6     O      False      4
7     O      False      4
8     S      False      4
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question! This can be achieved using the Pandas `apply` method with a class for maintaining the current count and the value of the last read group (in this case a boolean value). In my solution, the class `GroupCounter` has a `count` method, which accepts a boolean value, and it then either returns the current count or increments the count based on the value of the `switch_on` row being passed in. The resulting values are then assigned to a new column called `group`. See below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "point": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "N", "O", "O", "S"],
    "switch_on": [True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, False]
})


class GroupCounter:
    group_number = 1
    current_group = None

    def count(self, value: bool):
        # value will only be None if no rows have been read yet
        # this assumes no dataframe rows themselves have the value of None!!!
        if self.current_group is None:
            self.current_group = value

        # if the incoming value is different than that of the previous one
        # then increment the group number and capture the new group value
        if value != self.current_group:
            self.group_number += 1
            self.current_group = value

        return self.group_number


counter = GroupCounter()

df['group'] = df['switch_on'].apply(counter.count)

print(df.head(10))
```

Outputs:

```
  point  switch_on  group
0     A       True      1
1     B       True      1
2     C       True      1
3     A      False      2
4     D      False      2
5     N       True      3
6     O      False      4
7     O      False      4
8     S      False      4
```

Comment: Almost anything *can* be achieved using `apply`, but it's rarely the best way. Looping over a dataframe often defeats the purpose of using a dataframe.